# access another database(mssqlserver) in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing a CRM and i need to access customers database. whole CRM uses mysql to store data. but customers data stored in ms sqlserver.
by default to add another database in codeigniter,it should added from config file. but i want to add it using controller(like cms as wordpress,joomla,etc).

Answer (score 0):

well you cannot update database settings dynamically, as they're loaded long before the controller is initialized.

However, what you could do is, add another set of database config, write into the database.php file using codeigniter file helper using this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html).

```
write_file(APP_PATH.'/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');
```

Basically you open the file in write mode and set the database config into it.

This is one way of doing it. Just an idea.